# Android add fragment multiple times but just one instance found

Tags: android, android-fragments

My Activity contains one fragment with list of items.

Activity class:

```
    public class CategoryActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_subcategory);

        setupActionBar();

        CategoryFragment fragment = (CategoryFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.category_fragment);
        fragment.setBrand(mBrand);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        UIUtils.unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.RootView));
        CategoryFragment fragment = (CategoryFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.category_fragment);
        if(fragment != null)
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();

        System.gc();
    }

    public static class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {

        private ListView mListView;
        private CategoryAdapter mAdapter;
        private Category mRoot;
        private List<Category> mCategories;
        private Brand brand;

        public CategoryFragment(){}

        public void setBrand(Brand brand) {
            this.brand = brand;
        }

        private boolean mIsAnimating;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);
            mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

            try {
                if (mCategories == null) {
                    loadCategories(AppController.getInstance().getCategory());
                }

                if (mCategories != null) {
                    mAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(getActivity(), mRoot);
                    mAdapter.setListener(new CategoryAdapter.Listener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCategoryClick(String category) {
                            if (brand == null) return;

                            Utils.openQueryView(getActivity(), category, brand);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void openSubcategory(Category category) {
                            openSubcategoriesView(category);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onBrowseAllClick(Category category) {
                            if (brand == null) return;

                            if (category.name.equals(Category.ROOT)) {
                                Utils.openQueryView(getActivity(), category.name, brand);
                            } else {
                                Utils.openStoreActivity(getActivity(), category, brand);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                LOGD(TAG, e.getMessage());
                return view;
            }
            return view;
        }

        private void loadCategories(Category root) {
            // stuff here... it work well
        }

        private void openSubcategoriesView(Category category) {

            AnalyticsManager.sendScreenView(SCREEN_NAME);
            final CategoryFragment fragment = new CategoryFragment();
            fragment.setCategories(category);
            fragment.setBrand(brand);
            if (mIsAnimating) {
                return;
            }
            mIsAnimating = true;

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, 0, 0,
                    R.anim.slide_out_right);
            transaction.add(R.id.category_fragment, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

            mIsAnimating = false;

            List<Fragment> fs = getFragmentManager().getFragments();

            for(int i = 0; i< fs.size(); i++){
                LOGD(TAG, "fragment[" + i + "]: " + fs.get(i).getActivity());
            }
        }

        public void setCategories(Category category) {
            loadCategories(category);
        }
    }
}
```

Activity layout xml:

> ```
>     <fragment
>         android:id="@+id/the_main_fragment"
>         android:tag="firstFragment"
>               android:name="com.greelane.gapp.ui.CategoryActivity$CategoryFragment"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent" />
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:background="@drawable/header_shadow"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="12dp"></LinearLayout>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

Everytime I click on an item, a new **CategoryFragment** will be added to **FragmentManager** of this activity with the same Fragment class in xml layout (category_fragment id) as a child and if a child has its children, this conception will be repeated.

I try to log to see how many fragments I have, each time I clicked on an item:

Function **openSubcategoriesView**

```
List<Fragment> fs = getFragmentManager().getFragments();
// fs size > 1, but just one instance of CategoryFragment
           for(int i = 0; i< fs.size(); i++){
               LOGD(TAG, "fragment[" + i + "]: " + fs.get(i).getActivity());
           }
```

First time after navigating to activity I click on an item, it just creates one Fragment, so the **fs** size is 1;

Then I click back > Click on another item, I see that **fs** size is 2, but there is one instance of **CategoryFragment** I found.

I don't know how does it work with fragment in activity, but sometime my app crashes at this line of **onCreateActivity** setContentView(R.layout.activity_subcategory);

Error log:

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment

The line #14 start from this in my xml layout

> fragment
>               android:id="@+id/category_fragment" ...

So the question is:

1. Why I have just one instance of **CategoryFragment** after adding multiple times and how to fix this?
2. Why sometime I get inflate exception ad described above and how to fix this?

**#Updated1**

Error log for the second question, cannot find any exception stack trace:

```
01-21 11:16:54.276 16783-16783/? W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{vn.app.alezaa/com.greelane.gapp.ui.CategoryActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
01-21 11:16:54.279 16783-16783/? W/System.err: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
01-21 11:16:54.282 16783-16783/? W/System.err: Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.greelane.gapp.ui.CategoryActivity$CategoryFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
01-21 11:16:54.286 16783-16783/? W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.greelane.gapp.ui.CategoryActivity$CategoryFragment; no empty constructor
```

**#Updated2**

1. I cannot use `android:name=...CategoryActivity.CategoryFragment` instead of `android:name=...CategoryActivity$CategoryFragment` but still have same error
2. The empty contructor already had at first time I post this question.

I have editted my code to add new CategoryFragment like:

```
final CategoryFragment fragment = new CategoryFragment();
        fragment.setCategories(category);
        fragment.setBrand(brand);
        if (mIsAnimating) {
            return;
        }
        mIsAnimating = true;

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, 0, 0, R.anim.slide_out_right)
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment, category.title)// set tag is title of ctg
                .addToBackStack(category.title)
                .commit();

        mIsAnimating = false;

        List<Fragment> fs = getFragmentManager().getFragments();
// `error raised here after two times add CategoryFragment, the **fs** size > 1, but just one instance of it.`
        for(int i = 0; i< fs.size(); i++){
            LOGD(TAG, "fragment[" + i + "]: " + fs.get(i).getActivity());
        }
```

xml layout edited:

> ```
>     <fragment
>         android:id="@+id/the_main_fragment"
>         android:tag="firstFragment"
>         android:name="com.greelane.gapp.ui.CategoryActivity$CategoryFragment"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent" />
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:background="@drawable/header_shadow"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="12dp"></LinearLayout>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

Or do I need to seperate the CategoryFragment to other class and turn to non-static, cause now I cannot remove the static. Any ideas?

Comment: 2. You should attach full exception stacktrace. It'll be more information there.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question for loading same fragment multiple times you can check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding), where it says in Note section

> Each fragment requires a unique identifier that the system can use to
>   restore the fragment if the activity is restarted (and which you can
>   use to capture the fragment to perform transactions, such as remove
>   it). There are three ways to provide an ID for a fragment:
>
> - Supply the android:id attribute with a unique ID.
> - Supply the android:tag attribute with a unique string.
> - If you provide neither of the previous two, the system uses the ID of    the container view.

So you can use same fragment multiple times but you need to have **unique id and tag if added through layout.xml or unique tag if added through code.**

In your case you can consider using some unique field from Category object to be used as TAG when loading fragment, so every CategoryFragment instance you load will have unique tag and will be considered unique in fragmentmanager stack.

For your second question, two suggestions

1. change class attribute in fragment tag in xml to android:name and add fully qualified fragment class name i.e.
   `android:name = "mypackage.CategoryFragment"`
2. Also as per your crash if you check, it is mentioned **java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.greelane.gapp.ui.CategoryActivity$CategoryFragment; no empty constructor**. So create one empty or default constructor like

   public CategoryFragment(){

   }

Comment: Okay. Let me try this then feed back to you soon

Comment: Hi guy, I have set tag but still got the same error as described at my first question above.

Comment: Empty constructor needs to be there for fragments to be initiated. I would recommend to separate fragment as another class and then try.

Comment: Ok Rajen, I'm on the state of testing your recommendation. Will feedback to you soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

About this error I finally figured out

```
  List<Fragment> fs = getFragmentManager().getFragments();
// `error raised here after two times add CategoryFragment, the **fs** size > 1, but just one instance of it.`
        for(int i = 0; i< fs.size(); i++){
            LOGD(TAG, "fragment[" + i + "]: " + fs.get(i).getActivity());
        }
```

Based on the document,

> Calling commit() does not perform the transaction immediately. Rather, it schedules it to run on the activity's UI thread (the "main" thread) as soon as the thread is able to do so. If necessary, however, you may call executePendingTransactions() from your UI thread to immediately execute transactions submitted by commit(). Doing so is usually not necessary unless the transaction is a dependency for jobs in other threads.

So we need to wait a little time for the committion. It's ok right now.

But still waiting for testing about the second error I mentioned above. I will get update soon if have a good result.